# UISplitViewController consistent divider

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, ipad, uipopoverbackgroundview

In my iPad App I'm using a *UISplitViewController* with two *UINavigationControllers* as master and detail. In Potrait I'd like the master to be hidden and accessible via *UIPopoverViewController*. This is the implementation of my *UISplitViewController* subclass, which works fine:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        _splitViewController.delegate = self;

        _searchViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        _searchViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _masterNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_searchViewController];
        _masterNavController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

        _mapViewController = [[MapViewController_iPad alloc] init];
        _detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_mapViewController];
        _detailNavController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

        _splitViewController.viewControllers = @[_masterNavController, _detailNavController];
        _splitViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UISplitViewControllerDelegate

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
    svc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"ipad_search_vc_bar_button_title", @"Name of the master view controller button on iPad");
    [self.mapViewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    svc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.mapViewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController {
    svc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [pc setPopoverBackgroundViewClass:[CustomPopoverBackgroundView class]];
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

After starting the App the first time and tapping the *UIBarButton*, the master looks like the following:

[image]

After hiding and tapping the *UIBarButton* item the second time, the master looks like it's supposed to. It has the red divider line instead of the standard colored one:

[image]

Now, the *CustomBackgroundView* that is used in the *UISplitViewController* delegate is actually being instantiated, but somehow not used the first time around.

**Any idea how I could force the *UIPopOverController* to use the *CustomBackgroundView* the first time?**

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference between the last two pictures

Comment: First picture has a standard colored divider, second a red one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up simply adding a subview to the *UISplitViewController*'s view, which has the same color as the *UINavigationBar*.

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
[splitViewController.view addSubview:coloredView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Split View your root view controller? It looks like you have your split view within a Navigation Controller, which is not allowed. That would explain your graphical bugs.

Comment: Yes, the *UISplitViewController* is the root. It contains two *UINavigationController* which take care of the *UINavigationBar*.